# trying to concatenate a column into a comma delimited list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have 3 tables, 1 for products and one for categories the products are assigned to. what IM trying to do is concatenate the column called stCategoryName to a single column in a comma delimited list.

Basically I have the products table containing the primary key for each product and im trying to figure out how to concatenate all the stcategoryName column next to each product so i can have a simplified return

what im trying to get is the following.

```
stProductID     stCategoryName
123             category1,category2,category3


SELECT        
   dbo.StoreItemTracking.StCategoryID,
   dbo.StoreItemTracking.StProductID, 
   dbo.StoreItemTracking.viewOrder, 
   dbo.StoreCategories.StCategoryName, 
   dbo.Store_Products.PartNumber
FROM            
   dbo.StoreItemTracking 
   INNER JOIN dbo.StoreCategories 
      ON dbo.StoreItemTracking.StCategoryID = dbo.StoreCategories.StCategoryID 
   INNER JOIN dbo.Store_Products 
      ON dbo.StoreItemTracking.StProductID = dbo.Store_Products.ID
```

Im stuck as to how to concatenate a column where the query contains 3 tables to select from.

any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Look at using coalesce to turn category into a CSV:

See example:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeList varchar(100) 
SELECT @EmployeeList = COALESCE(@EmployeeList + ', ', '')  
    + CAST(Emp_UniqueID AS varchar(5))      
FROM SalesCallsEmployees  
WHERE SalCal_UniqueID = 1  
SELECT @EmployeeList
```

You can also use CTE's or Subqueries.  See:

```
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=createacommadelimitedlist
```

Another nice and easy example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21082/Concatenate-Field-Values-in-One-String-Using-CTE-i

This:

```
FId FName
--- ----
2    A
4    B
5    C
6    D
8    E
```

with:

```
;WITH ABC (FId, FName) AS
(
    SELECT 1, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(8000)) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.FId + 1, B.FName +  A.FName + ', ' 
    FROM (And the above query will return
SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY FId) AS RN, FName FROM tblTest) A 
    INNER JOIN ABC B ON A.RN = B.FId 
)
SELECT TOP 1 FName FROM ABC ORDER BY FId DESC
```

becomes:

```
FName
----------------------------
A, B, C, D, E,
```

Comment: Your query essentially becomes the preceding / first CTE.  Then the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand how your products and categories are connected but in general I do like this to create comma separated lists.

```
SELECT table1.Id
      ,Csv
FROM table1
     CROSS APPLY (
         -- Double select so we can have an alias for the csv column
         SELECT (SELECT ',' + table2.Name
                 FROM table2
                 WHERE table2.Id = table1.Id
                 FOR XML PATH('')
                ) AS RawCsv
     ) AS CA1
     CROSS APPLY (
         -- Trim the first comma
         SELECT RIGHT(RawCsv, LEN(RawCsv) - 1) AS Csv
     ) AS CA2
```